# When copy the url from one browser to another browser my session data are not coming in asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When i copy the URL from one browser to paste it in another browser my session data not retrieved it shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to access session values across multiple browsers.

Also, **you should check if the value exists in Session to avoid Server Error.**

```
if(Session["Key"] != null)
{
//Write your code here
}
else
{
 //Alternative code (redirection code)
}
```

Comment: i apply the session variable to one model.

Answer (score 1):

(Please note - this answer assumes you are not already using cookieless sessions)

The way sessions work in ASP.NET is that when you first access a site, a cookie-file is placed in your browsers cookie-store. The cookie contains a session ID, so the next time you access that site from that browser the ID is passed to the web-application and it knows which session-state to load.

However, each browser implements it's own cookie-store, so switching browsers means the site cannot determine your session ID.

One way to get around this is to use [cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx). However, these have a number of issues relating to usability and [security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic5), so think long and hard before deciding they are for you.

Another option is to [tie together your authorization and session systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066554/is-there-any-good-reason-why-the-authentication-cookie-and-the-session-state-coo). However, this is not generally recommended either.