# What are all the authentication options in asp.net core MVC

Tags: authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, session-state, asp.net-core-security

Like cookie authentication, I was trying to implement Session based authentication in my MVC Core 5.0 application but could not find any example to implement it. ? I have seen various example of storing the data in session and retrieving back but nowhere found for authentication and authorization purpose. Does session based authentication exists or just used to store the data for state management purpose? I thought Session authentication with Redis will be best for security so trying to implement it.

What other options I have for authentication so that I can choose best one?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of out-of-the-box authentication implementations in aspnetcore like Cookies, JWT, OpenIdConnection, WsFederation, Certificate, ...etc. to name a few.

There's no best or worse when it comes to choosing the method of authentication (e.g., You can't substitute certificate authentication for cookies) each authentication method has proper use. However, if you decided to go with JWT, for example, you can have a less-secured JWT and a more-secured JWT authentication, and that will be due to how you generate and validate the JWT token.

Instead of asking what is the best authentication method?. A better question will be what's the best authentication method for your specific use case.

HTTP is a stateless protocol, and sessions are a "hacky" way to track state in HTTP that's why  I would advise you against storing any user claims or authentication information in a session store. There's a good explanation [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202139/is-web-session-bad-design-why) why you should avoid sessions where possible. But of course, if you still want to do it this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6066732/1559258) explains how.